# Accurev on Raspberry PI?

Tags: raspberry-pi, accurev

I'd like to run the Accurev command line interface (CLI) on a Raspberry Pi.   Accurev's mostly written in Java, and Java runs on on the Pi, then it should work, right? :-)

Wondering if it's possible to launch the accurev client via java?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The AccuRev GUI is written in Java but the CLI is written in C/C++. This isn't something I've heard people have tried yet.